IIS Refused to apply inline style because it violates Content Security Policy but the domain is in style-src
In Windows Server 2019 IIS I added "Content-Security-Policy" to the HTTP Response Headers because I'm getting security issues.  I used the values:
style-src https://www.mydomainname.net 
or
style-src 'self'

With either entry, out styles are all messed up on the pages.  All our style sheets are written similar to:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Themes/3354/theme.css">

Which links to the root of the server name listed in the Content-Security-Policy.  I thought the entry meant "any stylesheet from the identified domain" would be acceptable but obviously it's not.  So, I'm not sure what's going on. Entering the fully qualified url for the domain doesn't seem to matter.  I read about unsafe-inline but that seems to go against the reason for adding a security policy.
My question boils down to: What does the style-src really mean (if not all css is good from this domain) and how to I get it to accept a Content-Security-Policy without messing up the site's web pages?

Anything embedded via <link rel="stylesheet" ...>is not inline styling. Inline styling is <style>...</style>, or <someelement style="..."> - or the equivalent of the latter, applied via JavaScript.

Well, that sure explains that!  I do have both 
It looks like your new post has some relevance to this question. Maybe you can check out my answer to see if it helps.
